# Cannot assign : must be a instance Django foreign Key error

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

I have created a model and connected a foreign key with it, but when I save them I get an error **Cannot assign "1": "SupplierBidModel.Load_ID" must be a "ShipperBoardModel" instance.**

I am fairly new to Django, and even newer to Django interconnected models concept. Any idea why this is happening ?? I have no idea where to go from here as there are not many questions such as this on Google either.

My models.py

```
class ShipperBoardModel(models.Model):
    # Manufaturer_ID
    LoadID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    From = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    To = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Length = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Weight = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Numberoftrucks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    MaterialType = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
    Loadingtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    # Loadkey = models.ForeignKey()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.Origin
#
class SupplierBidModel(models.Model):
    BidID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Load_ID = models.ForeignKey(ShipperBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=3)
    Supplier_ID = models.ForeignKey(SupplierBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=3)
    Bid_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)

  class Meta:
      unique_together = ('Load_ID', 'Supplier_ID')
```

Views.py

```
def suppliertablefun (request):  # function to display shipperboardmodel
    data = ShipperBoardModel.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forminput = BiddingForm(request.POST)
        if forminput.is_valid():
            forminput.save()

    forminput = BiddingForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'supplierboard/board.html', locals(), {'forminput': forminput})
```

PS: I am trying to prefill my form as such:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {# <input type="hidden" value={{item.LoadID}} name="Load_ID" /> #}
  <input type="hidden" value={{item.LoadID}} name="Load_ID" />
  {{ forminput.Bid_amount }}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I am trying to pass the current LoadID in the LoadID by using value = {{item.LoadID}} which is running because there a for loop in the template as such :

```
{% for item in data %}
```

Forms.py

```
class BiddingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Bid_amount = forms.IntegerField()
    Load_ID = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = SupplierBidModel
        exclude = ()
```

**Ok so I just fixed that error by pass value={{LoadID}} instead of `value={{item.LoadID}}` and there is no error, but it is not saving anything to the database. What to do now ?**

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code you are trying to assign a number (1) to `SupplierBidModel.Load_ID`, which is incorrect because you have the following in your `SupplierBidModel`:

```
Load_ID = models.ForeignKey(ShipperBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=3,related_name='load')
```

If you are creating the `ShipperBidModel` using a number to link the `ShipperBoardModel` then you need to get the corresponding object first, something along the lines of:

```
# ... you get load_id from the form
shipper_board = ShipperBoardModel.objects.get(pk=load_id)
# then you create the SupplierBidModel instance, adding the other fields that you want
SupplierBidModel.objects.create(LoadId=shipper_board)
```

Your `LoadId` is not an id, is an `ShipperBoardModel` object, so you need to assign the corresponding one.

Your naming convention is all over the place, model fields should be lowercase separated by underscores. Check the docs: [Model style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

Comment: Why is that ?? why cannot I pass a string value of "1" to LoadID ??? Also, thanks for the naming convention suggestion.

Comment: Check my edit. Your `LoadId` is not a number, is a ForeignKey to another model. So you have to assign it an instance of a `ShipperBoardModel`.

Comment: Oh..I certainly did not know that, so where do I add that  line`objects.create` to create an instance ? And what do I do so my prefilled form  can take a value from that for loop ?? Also, what is that shipper_board you created ? I am sorry I am very new to django apparently

Comment: The `shipper_board` is the ShipeprBoardModel instance that you need to use as LoadId, the id you get has to be used to get the proper instance first, the naming is confusing. That was just an example showing how it should work. Your SupplierBidModel is being created at some place, thats what you need to check.

Comment: I have added the `BiddingForm` in the question, is this where I add your code `shipper_board = ShipperBoardModel.objects.get(pk=load_id)` ?

Answer (score 1):

well you have some problem in the model

```
class SupplierBidModel(models.Model):
    BidID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Load_ID = models.ForeignKey(ShipperBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=3,related_name='load')
    Supplier_ID = models.ForeignKey(SupplierBoardModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=3,related_name='supplier')
    Bid_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

you cannot have more than one in a single model. for that you need related_name parameter

Comment: I just tried your code, it did not work....btw what is 'load' and 'supplier' here ??